# Monaco Editor Getting Line Number

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I am working on a project which will show the popup for the corresponding register number selected from the Monaco Editor.For that, I need the line number which is selected in the Monaco editor. How to get the particular line number from the editor and pass it to a javascript function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[You want to use IStandaloneCodeEditor.getPosition()](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.istandalonecodeeditor.html#getposition)